# Unable to redirect to HTTPS for secondary pages.

Tags: https

Need help as unable to solve and hosting co is unable to help either.

My first page is fine. if I type www.example.com, it will redirect to https. But other pages like for example:  www.example/latest-collection, if I type https://wwww.example.com/latest-collection, it work fine. However, if I just type wwww.example.com/latest-collection or https://wwww.example.com/latest-collection, it show a 500 or 404 error.

Comment: What server/language do you use?

Comment: Using English and Opencart.

Comment: apache and php it is ;-) Could you share your htaccess file?

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/ 
# Don't change the following two lines. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /moonriversg/$1 
# Change example.com to be your main domain again. 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain 
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?moonriver.com.sg$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ moonriversg/index.html [L]

Comment: Thanks Martin. I think I managed to solve it.